# C++ - Adding objects to an std::vector, instantiated in a loop

Tags: c++, collections, scope, instantiation

I'm an expert level Java programmer, trying to port my knowledge over to C++. This is not homework, just a concept that I'm trying to learn the C++ equivalent of.

What I'm trying to do, is "generate" a list of objects of a custom type using a loop. This is how I would do it in Java:

```
public class TestClass
{
   private ArrayList<ExampleClass> _exampleObjects;
   private int _numObjects = 10;

   public void populateList()
   {
      _exampleObjects = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();

      for(int i = 0; i < _numObjects; i++)
      {
         _exampleObjects.add(new ExampleClass());
      }
   }

   public void doStuffWithListItems()
   {
      for(ExampleClass e : _exampleObjects)
      {
         e.performAction();
      }
   }
}
```

Super simple stuff. Create a list, iterate through an arbitrary loop and add objects to it. Then, loop through those objects and use them for whatever purpose.

TestClass.h:

```
class TestClass
{
   public:
      // Constructor, copy constructor, destructor definitions

      void populateList();
      void doStuffWithListItems(); 
   private:
      std::vector<ExampleClass> _exampleObjects;
      const int _numObjects = 10;
};
```

TestClass.cpp:

```
void TestClass::populateList()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < _numObjects; i++)
   {
      ExampleObject obj;
      _exampleObjects.push_back(obj); 

      /* What actually goes here in place of obj? */
   }
}

void TestClass::doStuffWithListItems()
{
   for(auto it = _exampleObjects.begin(); it != _exampleObjects.end(); it++)
   {
      /* What do i do with my iterator to access my object? */
   }
}
```

Its my understanding that where I initialise my objects in the first loop, they go out of scope and die by the end of each loop iteration. Is that right? If so, how do I make a persistent instance?

I experimented with the shared_ptr<> from  and was apparently able to store them persistently, but couldn't for the life of me work out how to dereference from an iterator of a shared_ptr<>.

I feel like this should be a really simple concept. I just can't seem to work it out. I've read a lot on C++ scope and loops. I just can't seem to find anything on both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ExampleObject obj;
_exampleObjects.push_back(obj); 

/* What actually goes here in place of obj? */
```

Nothing.  What you have is correct, assuming `ExampleClass` has a working copy constructor.  If your compiler supports C++11 (and since you're using `auto`, it at least partially does), you can save yourself a copy.

```
_exampleObjects.emplace_back();
```

This constructs an object in place in the vector, forwarding the arguments (none in this case) to a matching constructor (the default ctor, in this case).  For accessing the object from the iterator, do this:

```
for(auto it = _exampleObjects.begin(); it != _exampleObjects.end(); it++)
{
   it->performAction();
}
```

Again, C++11 can make things better here.

```
for(auto & obj : _exampleObjects)
{
    obj.performAction();
}
```

> Its my understanding that where I initialise my objects in the first
>   loop, they go out of scope and die by the end of each loop iteration.

Correct.

> If so, how do I make a persistent instance?

`vector<>::push_back` takes care of this.  It copies the parameter into the vector.  In other words, it's not the same object that was created in the loop, it's a copy.  You just need to ensure that `ExampleClass` has non-broken copy semantics.

> couldn't for the life of me work out how to dereference from an
>   iterator of a shared_ptr<>

If you had an iterator into a vector of shared pointers, (call it `it`), you would dereference it, and call the member function of the stored object, like this:

```
(*it)->performAction();
// alternatively
(**it).performAction();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an ideal answer. :D

Comment: @ScottDrew: I added some additional information to clarify the questions you asked after the code, in case you still were wondering about that.

Comment: Thanks, the extra information really does help. I feel like I'm really starting to grasp C++ enough now to actually use it in a real project. I can't thank you enough for the lightning quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal answer suggests a very bad idea - use post increment ++ on iterator in loop.
You should never ever use it in loops where you only need to iterate because postincrement must return the value the iterator had before it was incrementing; so, that previous value needs to be copied somewhere before.
It is just not good from performance perspective and a bad codestyle sign.

Comment: You make a good point.  I wasn't really suggesting post-increment though, I was just copying the OP's loop, because that's not what the question was about.